# Is it OK to get a PSU that provides more wattage than is needed? {not a}

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I am starting on planning out a computer. I want to be able to expand the RAM and video cards without replacing the PSU, and I'm not sure if it's safe to get a PSU that provides 750W for a system that'll only require maybe 500W at first. Thanks, all!

Comment: Yes, overkill is a good thing....

Comment: It's *"safe"*, but the downsides are (1) cost. You're paying for more power capability that you won't be using.  (2) efficiency.  When the system is at idle, an over-capable PSU will be operating well outside its optimum power range, and use more electricity than a properly-sized PSU.

Comment: @sawdust I'm not an expert in PSU's but a PSU will only draw the amount of current that it needs. A 500w PSU is capable of powering 500w, but does not mean it will pull 500w at all times.

Comment: @DrZoo -- The PSU rating of watts is for the max power it can deliver.  The power that the PSU draws from the AC line is a function of its load (i.e. the power it is providing) and the (AC to DC conversion) efficiency.  This efficiency varies according to the load.  See http://superuser.com/questions/446419/will-a-500w-smps-consume-more-electricity-than-a-250w-smps-if-they-are-powering/446458#446458

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, yes. The rating of a power supply is the *maximum* that it can deliver. If its maximum is not required, it will deliver whatever is asked.

It is not a problem with computer power supplies, but some cheap, unregulated supplies (such as battery chargers) may give an increased voltage when not at full power.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried that getting a PSU with too high of a wattage would blow out components. This is my first build.

Comment: The wrong voltage can damage components, but a higher power rating will cause no problems: otherwise, you couldn't plug a 0.2A lamp into a 13A socket.