# Minimum wattage for my components?

Tags: power-supply

I have a PC I've already built, but I want to minimize it's footprint by getting a smaller case and smaller PSU. I've got a 600w SFX by corsair, but I want to move to a 300w black TFX by Silverstone.

Here are my components:

- Crucial 1TB M.2 SSD.
- Kingston 120GB M.2 SSD.
- ASUS STRIX Z270i motherboard.
- MSI GTX 1070 Aero.
- Intel i7-6700k
- Corsair SF600.
- Thermaltake Engine 27
- 2x 120mm black Noctua fans.
- 2x Kingston HyperX DDR4 16GB RAM.

What is the minimum wattage for this system, idle and under load? What could I trim off or change to reduce power usage?

Comment: Why would you want to move down to a 300w PSU? Your graphics card recommends a 500w PSU. If I were you, I would keep what you have or increase the capacity rather than decrease.

Comment: Note that the 600 watt power supply will not be drawing 600 watts if it isn't required. So dropping the max wattage rating may not save you much, if anything. *If* the PSU is dramatically over-rated for the draw, then at low wattage, your efficiency isn't that great, but 600 is not dramatic. Efficiency is a curve, but if efficiency is at 15%, then your actual power draw at the wall is whatever your computer calls for times 1.15 (so about 690 watts at the wall for 600 watt max load).

Comment: You don't want to push your PSU too close to its max, cause if you ever go over you could start seeing inconsistencies.
That being said, if you really want to see how small a PSU you can put in your system (maybe you've found a smaller form factor PSU?), your best bet is to actually measure your power consumption using [something like this](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Conserve-Insight-Monitor-F7C005Q/dp/B003WV5DBU/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1496867060&sr=8-3&keywords=kill-a-watt)

Comment: My point is that the differential between 300 and 600 supplies at idle is not going to be 300watts. It will be something more like (45w * 1.2) vs (45w * 1.4).

Comment: Try [Cooler Master's Power Supply Calculator](http://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/), it is super helpful.

Comment: @Yorik it's not about reducing the wattage, it's about reducing the physical footprint of the PSU, which unfortunately requires reducing the wattage for a TFX form factor PSU.

Comment: It's all a compromise - a high performance system will use more power. If you ditch the GPU and use the onboard one that will reduce your max power draw by close to 150 watts, and you MIGHT get away with 300 watts without it. Your CPU draws 91 watts. A low power variant will reduce performance but could save you 50 watts. This would mean you could also replace the fan with something lower power and quieter - your fan is rated at 70 watts!

Comment: @davidgo The fan is rated at 70w, but after testing the i7-6700k stays pretter decent around 70-75c under full load OC'd to 4.36GHz. Ditching the GPU is not possible, but I could go for an i7-700k or under-clock the i7-6700k for reduced wattage.

Comment: No way you could run your current system under load on a 300 watt PSU.

Comment: Replacing the CPU with a n i7-7700k will not reduce your heat loading - it also has a tdp of 91 watts. If you can't ditch the GPU it would be highly inadvisable to go to a significantly smaller PSU. Nvidea recommends a 500 watt PSU minimum.

Comment: IMO the best way to determine the power consumption is to actually measure it using a meter such as a Kill-a-Watt.  Too large a PSU is definitely inefficient.  See https://superuser.com/questions/446419/will-a-500w-smps-consume-more-electricity-than-a-250w-smps-if-they-are-powering/446458#446458  But do leave headroom for conditions (e.g. temperature) that reduce PSU output.

Comment: @Yorik -- An overcapacity PSU is _very_ inefficient when drawing less than 20% of its rated output, e.g. less than 120W for a 600W unit.  This is very easy to measure/confirm with a power meter such as a Kill-a-Watt.  A smaller, right-sized PSU can save 10W or more at idle.  See https://superuser.com/questions/446419/will-a-500w-smps-consume-more-electricity-than-a-250w-smps-if-they-are-powering/446458#446458

Comment: @sawdust: oh, i agree, the reason I didn't make an answer is that it is tangental. But I was presuming it would be below maximums as the OP was speaking about reducing hardware and making calculations. The main point (again) is that the load is what matters and the inefficiency at that load is the only real savings between a large PSU and a small one. But we have since learned that this is soley about getting a smaller physical PSU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to determine you system wattage is to find the wattage of each component and add them up.

Using the basic information provided in your post and the Cooler Master calculator linked in the comments, your system draws over 300 watts in its basic form.

A 300 watt power supply will be insufficient and should not be used. 400 watts is the absolute minimum, given the current configuration, and realistically, for system stability and component longevity, 500 or 600 watts should be a target PS size.

Comment: Any recommendations for component changes?

Comment: E.g. if I had 1 M.2, no extra fans and an i7-700?

Comment: Recommendations are not something we can do well here, but I'd suggest dropping the smaller SSD, going from the 1070 to the 1050 GPU, which runs entirely on board power and has a TDP around 45W IIRC, and dropping one of your memory sticks entirely (more than 8GB is overkill unless you're building a power system, and if you're building a power system you're not limited to a 300W PSU).