# Comparing Performance of Desktops vs Laptops

Tags: performance

So, there is not much clear answer lying around the internet, but I am still seeking for one. Supposed if I were to compare, a Desktop with Intel i5 6700K vs a Laptop with Intel i5 6700U; with the desktop being underclocked & TDP limited down to meet 6700U being overclocked.

In general sense, will both Desktop and Laptop perform the same or will there still be performance difference?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. You can check CPU performance benchmarks for the specific CPUs you want to compare; all other measures of "performance" depend on many other hardware-related factors and the concrete task whose performance you are measuring.

Comment: In most cases the desktop will be faster because it contains better (and larger) components.

Comment: @harrymc I disagree that a desktop CPU will be faster because it contains better or larger components.  While this may be true, there are quality notebooks and rubbish desktops.  A lot of the "better" in  desktop components have to do with "better able to handle heavier power draw", which would be moot if you underclocked the desktop variant and oveclocked the laptop variant - ignoring the instabilities and problems which can arrise from overclocking.

Comment: @davidgo: I'm not talking about the CPU but of the entire box: RAM, bus, controllers etc. A laptop doesn't have all the components for optimal performance, and mobile CPUs emphasize power consumption over performance. Some extreme gaming laptops achieve desktop performance, but they are costly and power-hungry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such CPU is the I5-6700k or I5-6700u according to the [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/88393/6th-generation-intel-core-i5-processors.html) which would be fairly authoritative.  In fact, I could not find ANY i5 or i7 6th gen CPU's with the same model number but in mobile and overclock-able versions.

Were such a beast to exist, it would most likely perform identically if according to the Intel Ark everything about the CPUs were the identical other then the clock speed - although that is not a given.   Looking at the [i5-6300U and i5-6300HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=88190,88959) - both mobile processors, they are entirely different beasts although they have similar names/numbers.  On the other hand a comparison between the i5-6500 and i5-6400T show them to be [pretty identical](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=88187,88185) save for clock speed, TDP and thermal disipation requirements.

This is unsurprising as Intel test their CPU's and put them in different bins depending on how they perform - ie the k and non-k version of the CPU likely come from from the same line with small variations in the quality of the materials being responsible for different performance.

I did ask a tangentially related question some time ago about about [power consumption of a couple of similar CPU's](https://superuser.com/questions/1251574/power-consumption-of-chips-at-idle) who's answers which might be of interest to you as well.