# Can I under volt my processor without causing damages?

Tags: cpu, battery, intel, undervolting

I have a Intel 1280p and the lowest clock speeds is around 400Mhz, times 20, so it tends to draw a lot of power at idle, is there a way to lower it without parking the cores to reduce power? it is fast enough and i've monitored power usage and opening and using apps only about 2-4 cores kick up to abour 1100Mhz.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*it tends to draw a lot of power at idle*" -- How do you know that? Are you conflating power consumption by the CPU and the PSU? Even with an 80Plus power supply, an over-capacity PSU will have a large power consumption at idle compared to a right-capacity PSU. Power supplies are simply not very efficient when working at less than 20% of full output.

Comment: 400 MHz times 20 is 8 GHz there absolutely is no way your processor has the type of capability.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah - I suspect he was looking at total threads.  That system has 6 performance cores and 8 efficiency cores.

Comment: Why don't you want to park cores?  That is exactly the way Intel have designed this to save energy - ie you park the performance cores when not doing things that require performance.

Comment: @davidgo - Even then it’s GHz not MHz

Comment: If you run windows, you can also use Power Management, and in the advanced section, specify to limit your CPU to say... 3% maximum. When doing this, I find that the power consumption significally drops. I created a power plan with this setting, and switch between that and my normal one depending on my usage. With the 3% plan, I can still watch youtube and stuff, gaming is also possible, but not ideal, so that's when I switch.

Comment: @sawdust I don't believe that is how PSU work. An "over sized" PSU will still only draw the energy required for the system at a given time and state. A quality PSU that is rated for more, even significantly more, power output capability than the max system draw will last longer and produce that energy more efficiently due to the fact the system's max draw does not stress it.

Comment: @music2myear -- Believe whatever you want, but the facts on are my side.  See https://superuser.com/questions/446419/will-a-500w-smps-consume-more-electricity-than-a-250w-smps-if-they-are-powering

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the CPU is the main cause of your power draw.  That CPU has a TDP of 28 watts, so when its idle it will be drawing a fraction of that.

From a hardware point of view it is safe to undervolt your processor, but it is unlikely you will be able to do this on your CPU as Intel apparently don't support undervolting that CPU.  (Undervolting could cause crashes and data corruption)